# Operation on void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, void

It is known that void pointer airthmetic  is invalid.

```
int main {
    int b = 10;
    void *a = (void *) &b;
    void *c = a + 1;
    printf ("%p\n", a);
    printf ("%p\n", c);
}

    Output:
     0x7fff32941d1c             
     0x7fff32941d1d
```

I have read that above airthmetic is unexpected behaviour and we cannot rely on it.

Now moving on to actual question. I am taking an array of void pointers.

```
int main()
{
    void *a[10];
    void **b = a;
    void **c = (a + 1);
    printf ("%p\n", b);
    printf ("%p\n", c);
}

Output:
0x7fff8824e050          
0x7fff8824e058
```

Can you please explain the above behavior, where a double pointer (pointer to a void pointer is used). Is it expected behavior?

Comment: Example 1 is not undefined behavior, it is not even valid C and will not compile. If it compiles, you are using a non-standard compiler setup, that treats `void*` arithmetic as `char*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can you please explain the above behavior, where a double pointer (pointer to a void pointer is used). Is it expected behavior?

Yes, it is expected behavior.

That's because the size of the object the pointer points to is known. It is `sizeof(void*)`.

If the values of the pointers are expressed in purely integral values,

```
(a + 1) == a + 1*sizeof(void*)
```

It appears that on your platform, `sizeof(void*)` is `8`.